# how to declare functions using linq-to-xml queries?

Tags: vb.net, function, linq-to-xml

I'm new to vb.net and linq-to-xml. I am trying to encapsulate often used queries into functions so I can chain them after.

```
From tag in myelement where ... select ...
```

Above, myelement can be a IEnumerable(Of XElement) or a XElement, and visual studio have no problems with that. But if I define a function

```
Function select_items(ByRef myelement As IEnumerable(Of XElement), ByVal name As String) As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    Dim tags = _
        From tag In myelement.Elements(ns + "item")
        Where tag.Element(ns + "cc").Attribute("S") = "ITEM" _
        AndAlso tag.Element(ns + "cc").Value = name
        Select tag
    Return tags
End Function
```

If I put no type for myelement, i have the error

```
Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.
```

If I put "myelement As Xelement" in the function declaration then I call the function with a IEnumerable(of XElement) in argument, it show an error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Xml.Linq.XElement]' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.
```

If I put "myelement As IEnumerable(of Xelement)" and call it with a XElement, I get the same error reversed

So the question is: how should I declare my function to have the same kind of polymorphism the from/in/where/select statement have ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Elements` on both `XElement` and `IEnumerable(Of XElement)`, but both are not calling the same method!

First one is really [`XContainer.Elements(name as XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) method call (you can call it with `String` parameter, because there is [`Implicit(String to XName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit.aspx) conversion provided). The second one is an extension method set on [`IEnumerable(Of T As XContainer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784.aspx).

To make your method work with both `XElement` and `IEnumerable(Of XElement)` (or more general with `XContainer` and `IEnumerable(Of XContainer)` you have to provide two methods as well:

```
Function select_iems(ByRef myelement As XContainer, ByVal name As String) As IEnumerable(Of XContainer)
    Return select_items(New List(Of XContainer)(1) From {myelement}, name)
End Function

Function select_items(ByRef myelement As IEnumerable(Of XContainer), ByVal name As String) As IEnumerable(Of XContainer)
    Dim tags = _
        From tag In myelement.Elements(ns + "item")
        Where tag.Element(ns + "cc").Attribute("S") = "ITEM" _
        AndAlso tag.Element(ns + "cc").Value = name
        Select tag
    Return tags
End Function
```